# Unable to execute onClick function in mapped ellement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, event-listener

I am trying to add an on click function to my list tags that are mapped from an array, i.e:

```
{this.props.addresses.map((address, index) =>
   <li key={`address-${index}`} onClick={this.addressClick}>{address.prediction}</li>
)}
```

addressClick is defined in constructor like this:

```
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.addressClick = this.addressClick.bind(this)
  }
```

and as a function in the class like this

```
  addressClick () {
    console.log('Clicked')
  }
```

When I click on my list tag nothing happens, I don't see any console statements.

Comment: where is the mapping code - render method? Maybe, this.addressClick is undefined there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Suggestion

You can implement this by passing the index to another function and then call `addressClick()`.

```
function clickListener ( index ) {
    var clickedAddress = addresses[index];
    addressClick(clickedAddress.prediction);
}
```

### Result:

```
{this.props.addresses.map((address, index) =>
    <li key={`address-${index}`} onClick={`clickListener(${index})`}</li>
)}
```

Answer (score 2):

Bind this to the map method:

```
{this.props.addresses.map((address, index) =>
   <li key={`address-${index}`} onClick={this.addressClick}>{address.prediction}</li>
).bind(this)}
```

Comment: You also can pass `this` as second argument to `map()` and avoid the binding. And BTW, it should be `this.props.addresses.map.bind(this)(()=>{...})`, isn't it?

Comment: Forget the second part of my comment. It's wrong as it would call this.map, that it is not what we want. I think that the only way to bind externally is through the 2nd parameter of `map()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work unless I am missing something.  This works for example:

```
const arr = [1,2,3,4]

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.addressClick = this.addressClick.bind(this)
  }

  addressClick () {
    console.log('Clicked')
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {arr.map((address, index) =>
          <li key={`address-${index}`} onClick={this.addressClick}>{address}</li>
        ) }
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
```